# Confusing whitespace issue in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I have two versions of a document encoded in one TEI XML and wish to output one of the versions to a text file. Here’s the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Publication Information</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Information about the source</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
      <body>
         <p>John Q Doe was born in 
            <app>
               <rdg wit="text1">Omaha</rdg>
               <rdg wit="text2">Lincoln</rdg>
            </app>
        in 1950. But was he
            <app>
               <rdg wit="text1">happy</rdg>
               <rdg wit="text2">glad</rdg>
            </app>?
        Some say no.
         </p>
      </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

And here’s the sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:teiHeader">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:app">       
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="tei:rdg[@wit='text1']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Cancel out the alternate version of the text-->
    <xsl:template match="tei:rdg[@wit='text2']">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want to output is “John Q Doe was born in Omaha in 1950. But was he happy? Some say no.” What I end up with is “John Q Doe was born inOmahain 1950. But was hehappy? Some say no.” So,  I somehow need to preserve a single space around the app elements. I can’t `preserve-space()` because I use extra whitespace for readability, and I can’t simply use `<xsl:text>` to insert spaces on the template match for `tei:app`, because sometimes punctuation comes immediately after the `<app>` element, as does the question mark above. I’m stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you essentially want a special case of `normalize-space()` that just does the normalizing of runs of whitespace (*including* at the start and end of the string) down to a single space, without also stripping leading and trailing whitespace.  Since you're in XSLT 2.0 you can do that with a simple regular expression:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+', ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You would also need to add

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

to the top of the stylesheet in order to suppress text nodes that are *entirely* whitespace.  Without that you'll end up with an extra space in your output for each all-space text node (e.g. between `<text>` and `<body>`, `<body>` and `<p>`, `</rdg>` and `</app>`, etc.).  The `strip-space` directive only affects all-whitespace text nodes, it does not affect the whitespace within text nodes that also contain useful non-space content.

Comment: Now this is close, and logically, it seems like it should do the trick. But when I actually run the transformation, I get: "    John Q Doe was born in  Omaha   in 1950. But was he  happy  ? Some say no.    " This isn't displaying right, but there are 4 spaces before "John", 2 spaces before "Omaha" and 3 after, 2 spaces before "happy" and 3 after, and 4 spaces after "no."

Comment: If we add `<xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>` to `<xsl:template match="tei:app">`, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel the simplest fix for this would be to add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to the top of the stylesheet.  This will make it completely ignore text nodes that are _entirely_ whitespace, but won't affect text nodes that contain some whitespace and some content.

Comment: Ha, a big "duh" moment for me! Thanks much, I forgot I'd taken out `xsl:strip-space` when I was fiddling around with `normalize-space()`

Comment: @Daniel the only case you need to watch out for is if you have two adjacent `app` elements, as the `strip-space` would remove the space between them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the missing spaces. 
If you put a `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` you will get a space before and after the  elements:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:rdg[@wit='text1']">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives following output:

```
John Q Doe was born in Omaha in 1950. But was he happy ? Some say no
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost gets us there. But the complicating factor is the question mark. I didn't originally go with the `<xsl:text>` option because there shouldn't be a space between "happy" and "?"